# First installation of application it working good but when i reinstall the application it give me this error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61)
  at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.(FileLockCommunicator.java:51)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:263)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:255)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:108)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:95)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:90)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.updateFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:51)        at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.update(SimpleStateCache.java:87)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator$1.create(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:50)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.doUpdate(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:67)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.update(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:47)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.store(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:232)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater.onStart(DaemonRegistryUpdater.java:80)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:171)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.doAction(DaemonMain.java:125)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
  at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
  at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
  Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
  at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84)
  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:131)
  at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:394)
  at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:244)
  at java.base/java.net.DatagramSocket.(DatagramSocket.java:301)
  at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator.(FileLockCommunicator.java:49)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get error
`Address already in use: Cannot bind` because the first instance is already running, you need to kill/close the first installation before starting another

Comment: It worked after killing the first installation. Flutter Window   taskkill /F /IM dart.exe